# Use of uninitialized value $stdout1 at line 15

Tags: perl

This script is used to connect to a switch and print its list of vlan, but the output is:

`Use of uninitialized value $stdout1 at line 15`

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
no strict;
my $host     = "10.220.15.24";
my $user     = "admin";
my $password = "admin";
my $ssh      = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$ssh->login( $user, $password );
print "check the version of the build \n";
print "enter the config mode \n";
print " ahmed ";
my ($stdout1) = $ssh->cmd("show vlan");
print $stdout1 ;
```

Comment: at ligne 15 , not at 12 , please help !!

Answer (score 4):

Rule 1 of writing perl. `use strict;` `use warnings;`.

Turning it off again with `no strict` doesn't count!

But even with `strict` turned on - I can't replicate your problem. All I can think of is that the `Net::SSH::Perl` `cmd` function isn't returning a result.

You may want to check it more explicitly:

```
my ($result, $errors, $exitcode ) = $ssh->cmd("show vlan");
print "$exitcode $errors\n";
print "$result\n";
```

I'm guessing that something's going wrong with your connection (invalid password maybe?)

Comment: mon probleme c'est  de se Connecter un commutateur non et recuperer sa liste de vlan

Comment: Ahmed: Please reply to comments in English. Machine translation of above: "My problem is to connect a switch and not recover sá list vlan"

Answer (score 3):

You turned off `strict`? Why? If you were having problems, solve the problem, and don't ignore it.

- You need to check the return values of your various commands. Did `ssh->login` work? Did `Net::SSH::Perl->new`? Use `or die` to verify they actually returned something.
- Read the documentation. `ssh-cmd` returns a three member array:

  - `STDOUT`.
  - `STDERR`.
  - The exit status.

Notice in this program, I check the return of each method to the `Net::SSH::Perl` class.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);   # Replaces 'print' with 'say'

use Net::SSH::Perl;

use constant {
    HOST        => '10.220.15.24',
    USER        => 'admin',
    PASSWORD    => 'admin',
};

my $ssh  = Net::SSH::Perl->new( HOST ) 
    or die qq(Can't SSH to host.);

$ssh->login( USER, PASSWORD );
    or die qq(Can't log into host.);

say "check the version of the build";
say "enter the config mode";
say " ahmed ";
my ( $stdout, $stderr, $exit_code ) = $ssh->cmd("show vlan")
    or die qq(Can't execute command.);
if ( $exit_code ) {
    say "Command returned an exit code of $exit_code"
}
say $stdout;
```

You can also pass the `debug` option when you create your `$ssh` object:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new( HOST, { debug => 1 } );
```

This may give you a few more clues to what is going on.

Comment: thank you for your help, but when I execute the script to me it shows "  use of uninitialized value $stdout  at line 28

Comment: @ysth It took me a while, but yes it was. Thanks.